# Does Microsoft AJAX jscript $find not work on hidden / non-visible elements?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Does Microsoft AJAX jscript $find not work on hidden / non-visible elements?
I can't seem to get it work but I don't know if this is expected behavior.

Comment: Why not just use document.getElementById("foo") which will work with non-visible elements?

Comment: I agree with jfriend00; you can use $get as a shortcut to the getElementById method

Comment: $get, $find,document.getElementById("foo") all find elements in the DOM, no matter what CSS is applied(display:none;visibility:hidden...etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set the `Visible` property of a control to `false`, then `$find` will not find anything, because asp.net doesn't generate html for the controls with `Visible` property set to `false`. But it should work if your using css/javascript to hide control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive the element is in the DOM(ie:Visible=True)?  Here is some [reference info](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) as to expected behavior:

`$find` actually calls `findComponent`:

```
Sys.Application = new Sys._Application();
window.$find = Sys.Application.findComponent;

findComponent: function _Application$findComponent(id, parent) {
        /// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.Application.findComponent">Finds top-level components that were added through addComponent if no parent is specified  or children of the specified parent. If parent is a component</summary>
        /// <param name="id" type="String">The id of the component to find.</param>
        /// <param name="parent" optional="true" mayBeNull="true">The component or element that contains the component to find.  If not specified or null, the search is made on Application.</param>
        /// <returns type="Sys.Component" mayBeNull="true">The component, or null if it wasn't found.</returns>
        //#if DEBUG
        var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
            {name: "id", type: String},
            {name: "parent", mayBeNull: true, optional: true}
        ]);
        if (e) throw e;
        //#endif
        // Need to reference the application singleton directly beause the $find alias
        // points to the instance function without context. The 'this' pointer won't work here.
        return (parent ?
            ((Sys.IContainer.isInstanceOfType(parent)) ?
                parent.findComponent(id) :
                parent[id] || null) :
            Sys.Application._components[id] || null);
    },
```